# Vertical linear gradient color in flutter

Tags: flutter, material-ui, linear-gradients

I have a container which has a side border and the color, I'm handling it by using stops property in BoxDecoration
Here is the code

```
Container(
      // margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10)
      margin: StaticData.isTablet
          ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, right: 80, top: 15, bottom: 10)
          : EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 2),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          width: 1.5,
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
        ),
        gradient: appointmentModel.apptUsersModel != null
            ? LinearGradient(stops: [
                0.02,
                0.02
              ], colors: [
                Color(int.tryParse("0xFF" +
                    (appointmentModel.apptUsersModel!.first!.color
                            ?.split("#")
                            .last ??
                        ""))!),
                Colors.white
              ])
            : LinearGradient(
                stops: [0.02, 0.02], colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white]),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey,
            blurRadius: 5,
          ),
        ],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          _todayAppointmentCardTableView(appointmentModel),
          Visibility(
            visible: widget.homeBloc!.professionalUserTypeId != null &&
                    widget.homeBloc!.professionalUserTypeId == 4
                ? false
                : true,
            child: Divider(
              thickness: 1,
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
              visible: widget.homeBloc!.professionalUserTypeId != null &&
                      widget.homeBloc!.professionalUserTypeId == 4
                  ? false
                  : true,
              child: _todayActionListWidgets(appointmentModel)),
        ],
      ));
```

this is the result [image]

the color represents user assigned to the appointment
if there are multiple users I want the color accordingly divided in that vertical section So how can I achieve it?
Any Help is Appreciated.

Comment: would another user be another container of the image? or just another row of 'Name:' ?

Comment: @Texv nothing would be shown in the UI just if there is another user assigned to it color would be displayed in the side border making it 2 colors in the side border occupying 50% each vertically